# Why is the Edit View link not appearing in Panels?

Tags: views, panels, navigation

I've got a Views block display placed inside a Panels pane.  It works well, and I wanted to add two similar blocks, so I cloned the View and changed the necessary settings. The original block has the cogwheel "Edit View" contextual link, but the clones do not. Any ideas? I can still go to Structure -> Views -> name to edit, but it's much easier to use the contextual link. If anyone knows why it isn't appearing and how to get it back, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer by accident yesterday. When adding a Views block to a Panels pane, Panels will ask you if you want the "Master" or "Block" display. I'm not sure there's a difference in the output at all, but if you select the "Block" display, the contextual cogwheel "Edit View" link will not show up.  If you select "Master", it will.  Unfortunately, you can't change the display once it has been added, so you need to remove the "Block" display and re-add it, selecting the "Master" display.  This could cause you to have to redo some work, if you had spent any time configuring things already.